how can I get underlying timeslot clicked on when I click on an event which spans multiple timeslots
I would like to get the underlying timeslot of a click when the click occurs on an event which spans multiple timeslots
My reason for wanting the timeslot is to be able to create extra events on top of existing events with differing start and end times.
The usual hook eventClick does not seem to provide this information.  Other hooks like select and dateclick don't seem to get triggered when an event is present on a timeslot.
I have tried adding css classes to the event containing timeslot information and looking for the class in the hook but seems difficult.
Also, looked at using pixels of the click but this also seems not very clean.

This is not supported by fullcalendar unfortunately.

I don't know why you would create an event just based on whereabouts in the event the user clicked though. I'm not sure users are all that careful

ohh, how would you normally go about creating an event at a particular time?  Is clicking and dragging over a time range?  If this was the case, I think it would still be helpful to create an event which spans a subset of the time range of another event.

You can create events by handling the "select" callback

does select get called if the click is on an existing event?  As far as I can see it does not.

No, it's only called if you click on an empty space. There's always a little bit of empty space to the right of an event, in the timeGrid view, which will respond to that. It's not super-easy to select it, but it's possible. If you want to create events by clicking on an existing event, you can use eventClick to handle the click, and then pop up your own form to ask the user to confirm the exact timing of the event - you could use the start/end of the clicked event as default values if you like, but you can't do anything more detailed from the eventClick callback unfortunately

If you think this should be an enhancement you can look at how to request that here: https://fullcalendar.io/requesting-features
